# Storing an image from the web for one session (in Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am following a tutorial about getting images from the web and storing them on the phone in Swift. For my purpose, I would like to know how I could only store them for one 'session', which means until the user stops using the app. The reason is that I want to change the image of the url every day. 
Anyone any idea?

```
  @IBOutlet var overLay: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    let url = NSURL(string: "http://test.com")

    // Update - changed url to url!

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
        response, data, error in

        if error != nil {

            println("There was an error")

        } else {

            let image = UIImage(data: data)

            // self.overLay.image = image

            var documentsDirectory:String?

            var paths:[AnyObject] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

            if paths.count > 0 {

                documentsDirectory = paths[0] as? String

                var savePath = documentsDirectory! + "/overLay.jpg"

                NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(savePath, contents: data, attributes: nil)

                self.overLay.image = UIImage(named: savePath)

            }

        }


    })

}
```

thank you so much!

Comment: What is you thought process on going this route instead of using NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only interested in keeping the image for the lifecycle of the app, it's perfectly viable to just hold a pointer to a UIImage object in memory, likely via some long-living object (AppDelegate would be a possible choice here).

Since you already have a UIImage from the data coming down the pipe, I'd simplify your code as such, or if you want to use some Singleton like the AppDelegate to manage the image state, see what happens when `iWantToUseAppDelegate` is set to true

```
 @IBOutlet var overLay: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let iWantToUseAppDelegate = false // for demonstration purposes


    let url = NSURL(string: "http://test.com")

    // Update - changed url to url!

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
        response, data, error in

        if error != nil {

            println("There was an error")

        } else {

            let image = UIImage(data: data)


            if iWantToUseAppDelegate {
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! YourAppDelegateClass // YourAppDelegateClass has some property called "cachedImage"
                appDelegate.cachedImage = image
                self.overLay.image = appDelegate.cachedImage

            } else {
                self.overLay.image = image
            }

        }


})
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much! But, I am very new and I tried to search for something with CachedImage in the app delegate, but I couldn't find that. :( I am so sorry, do you have any idea what it would be exactly?

Comment: Ooooh, I understand now. It gives an error saying 'expected type after 'as' in the line : let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!YourAppDelegateClass

Comment: Awwwww, nope. Still having the same error. I thought I solved it... Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So, YourAppDelegateClass would be the name of your AppDelegate subclass in this case. In most Xcode projects, that's just AppDelegate.swift, if I recall correctly. And you'd need to define a writable property on that class for us to store the image in, in this case named "cachedImage" -- it's not just there for you to use, you need to define it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to tweak a few things but this code might work a little easier. 
Used what mindfreek add to correct the code.

```
@IBOutlet var overLay: UIImageView!
var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults()
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



let url = NSURL(string: "http://test.com")

// Update - changed url to url!

let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue:      NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
    response, data, error in

    if error != nil {

        println("There was an error")

    } else {

        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        NSUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(image!), forKey: "image")
        if let imagedSaved: AnyObject = defaults.valueForKey("image")
        { overLay.image = image }
        else { NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSUserDefaults().dataForKey("image")!) as UIImage }



    }


})
```

Comment: You can't save an UIImage to user defaults like this

Comment: NSUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(image), forKey: "image")

Comment: NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSUserDefaults().dataForKey("image")!) as UIImage

Comment: Dear Leonardo, your suggestions seems really good. I have this now, but what to do with: if let imagedSaved = defaults.valueForKey("image")?

Comment: let image = UIImage(data: data)
                NSUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(image), forKey: "image")
        
                if let imagedSaved = defaults.valueForKey("image"){
                overLay.image = image
                } else {
                    NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSUserDefaults().dataForKey("image")!) as UIImage
                }

Comment: Is there an easier way to share the current bit of code?

Comment: mindfreek if you want it to look like mine above you have place it in answer and not a comment.  I used your suggestion with a couple of tweaks because Xcode recommended.